# How to avoid alternate background drawing for empty NSCollectionView row views?

Tags: cocoa, nscollectionview

as the title says, I don't want NSCollectionView to draw the alternate color if the row is empty. By default NSCollectionView draws alternate rows all over the visible area even if you have just a few rows (I'm using 1 column n rows btw).

Comment: good question, I wonder the same!